# ajax return Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm using ajax in my HTML file and I'm trying to get JSON data. But when I click on a button that fires the ajax I get an Unexpected token error. This console says the mistake is between colon and apostrophe.

`{"trip_origin_address": "colima, 324a, ... }`

This is my code:

```
function cancel() {

  id = $('#numero').val();
      if(id == ""){
        alert("Selecciona un numero primero");
      return;
      }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://line-76299minutos.appspot.com/2/delivery/client/track',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: 'tracking_id=' + id + '&f=json',
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function (result) {},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
  });

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the console error handy?

Comment: https://line-76299minutos.appspot.com/2/delivery/client/track this link can not be reached.

Comment: The server returns JSON but you told jQuery to expect JSONP. Despite the similar name, JSON and JSONP are very different. If the server doesn't support CORS or JSONP, you cannot make an Ajax request to it. JSONP is **not** a magic bullet that lets you make requests to servers that don't support CORS. JSONP has to be supported by the server. Check their API docs.

Comment: Look at all the duplicates: [`[jquery] ajax unexpected token jsonp`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+ajax+unexpected+token+jsonp)